# Redirecting to www

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I've added a global.asax to my web project, and I'm trying to check if the domain in the `Begin_Request` contains "www", and if it doesn't, then redirect them to the page they were requesting, but with the "www" pre-pended to it.  For an example, If I try to access : SampleSite.com, it directs me to SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/www.SampleSite.com/index.aspx

Here is the code:

```
<script runat="server">
    Sub Begin_Request(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.BeginRequest
        Dim domain As String = Request.Url.Host
        If (Not domain.StartsWith("www")) Then
            Dim path As String = ""
            path = String.Format("www.{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(7))
            Response.Redirect(path)
        End If

    End Sub
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use ASP.NET for this. Use IIS's URL Rewriting feature instead, it has a built-in rule for this called "Canonical domain name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should do this by code but using IIS redirect features. [Here](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html) you have an example about how to do it on IIS 7

In case you still want to stay with this approach, change

```
String.Format("www.{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(7));
```

by

```
String.Format("{0}://www.{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(7));
```

Comment: Agreed, you probably don't want this in code - check out this post on Scott Forsyth's blog on IIS Rewrite (http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www) - he's a wealth of IIS information in general